# Extract multiple numbers from a string without commas

Tags: python

I'm recently trying to use my RFID card's UID but I'd like the UID to be like `11217924711571` instead of `[112, 179, 247, 115, 71]`. I've tried `int(re.search(r'\d+', uid_str).group())` but it only returns `112`. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: So you want to join the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
old = [112, 179, 247, 115, 71]
new = ''.join(map(str, old)) # will be a str
new_int = int(new) # if you need it to be an integer, convert it
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!